# What is the commandment of Islam about the widow of shaheed?

Tags: fiqh, islamic-philosophy, shahada

As we know that shaheed have a great status in heaven and we believe according to our learning that shaheed always alive they never died. But according to the rules shaheed wife also called as widow of that person (shaheed). As I am confused in getting this point that if shaheed is alive and we also don't call shaheed as a died person then what commandments about widow of a shaheed in Islam?
Is she have permission to nikah(marriage) any other person after completing her eddat?

Comment: Why should the widow not be allowed to marry someone else?

Comment: I am asking that point

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's true as you said the shaheed are alive they are not die but at this same time they have no connection to the world they are alive in our golden words and his wife who is now a widow she can marry any one else like as every other women's do after completing her eddat according to the Islamic calendar.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how her husband died or benefits to him in jannah (or even for argument's sake, what happens to him in jahannam). After the 'iddah (four months and ten days on the Islamic calendar) she can remarry according to the general marriage rules and requirements (Surah Al-Baqarah 2:222: 2:234-235). However, depending on the society one lives in, it may bring unwanted attention from authorities or may cause problems for the woman after she remarries; some societies think that although she *may* remarry after 'iddah that it's inappropriate to do so.

In other words there's no commandment specifically regarding what you mention, but there are other implications and issues involved.